# Property or method "index" is not defined. When create new item Vue.js

Tags: vue.js, undefined

I have a button that creates new elements, when I create a new element I add it to the 'added' array and I do a v-for, I try to pass the index to be able to enumerate but it tells me that it is not defined

In the **parent** template:

```
<tr is="child" v-for="(item, index) in added" :key="index" v-on:remove="added.splice(index, 1)"
                            :id="item.id"
                            :name="item.name"
                            :lastname="item.lastname"
                            :pack="item.pack"
                            :type="item.type"
                            :size="item.size"
                            :color="item.color">
 </tr>
```

In the **child** template.

```
<tr class="no-border-top">
    <th class="align-middle" scope="row">{{ index }}</th>
</tr>
```

**Log:**

> [Vue warn]: Property or method "index" is not defined on the instance but referenced during render. Make sure that this property is reactive, either in the data option, or for class-based components, by initializing the property. See: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html#Declaring-Reactive-Properties.

Comment: You're not passing index as a prop. Besides you could just use `item.id` as a key, assuming that is unique.